# How do I enable opening a file by double clicking?

Tags: 11.10, nautilus, files

I've never had this problem before. I just upgraded to 11.10 and now clicking or dubleclicking a file doesn't cause it to run in its associated program. Clicking works on the unity bar all right, but not on files or folders. I have to right click, and select open. It's a pain!

Comment: Does this happen with all file formats? All the files you have (movie, mp3, libreoffice, etc) need a double click to open? Does this happen with the guest account also?

Answer (score 3):

With the Desktop or your Home folder open, from the menu bar, choose: *Edit* -> *Preferences* -> *Behaviour* and look at the options in the first group of radio buttons.

Comment: Perfect. Just what I needed to open .erb files in gedit. Thanks.